# flutter's clipRRect widget is now showing on the screen

Tags: flutter

I am currently implementing my page using the flutter.

The state management library is using GetX.

In this situation, I created MyPageView, which is dependent on MyPageController, and each controller and view are as follows.

```
// mypage_view
class MyPageView extends BaseView<MyPageController> {
  @override
  Widget body(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          _buildUserProfileContainer(),
          Container(
            height: AppValues.margin_12,
            color: AppColors.containerBackgroundGreyColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildUserProfileContainer() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: AppValues.margin,
        right: AppValues.margin,
        top: AppValues.margin_32,
        bottom: AppValues.margin_32,
      ),
      child: Obx(
        () => Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              child: (() {
                if (controller.userUiModel == null ||
                    controller.userUiModel!.photo == null) {
                  Container(
                    color: AppColors.buttonBgColor,
                    height: 88,
                    width: 88,
                  );
                } else {
                  NetworkImage(controller.userUiModel!.photo!);
                }
              }()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// mypage_controller
class MyPageController extends BaseController {
  void initData() async {
    try {
      String uid = uid;
      String userCreateRequestString = await searchUserData(uid);

      Map<String, dynamic> map =
      jsonDecode(userCreateRequestString) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      map['phoneNumber'] = _firebaseAuthManager.getCurrentUser()!.phoneNumber;
      setUserUiModel(UserUiModel.fromJson(map));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<String> searchUserData(String uid) async {
    return _preferenceManager.getString(uid);
  }

  final Rxn<UserUiModel> _userUiModel =
      Rxn<UserUiModel>(null);

  UserUiModel? get userUiModel => _userUiModel.value;

  void setUserUiModel(UserUiModel value) =>
      _userUiModel.value = value;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    initData();
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

Currently, I receive user data from shared Preferences and initialize it in the controller's onInit stage.

Through debug, it was confirmed that the UserUiModel value was initialized normally.

The widget tree consists of the following:

[image]

In this situation, I have no reason why ClipRect's child is not visible on the screen.

If you insert a widget such as Text in the ClipRect position, it can be seen normally on the screen.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Uh... I was very foolish...
NetworkImage was class, not a widget....
The solution was to change NetworkImage to Image.network.... OMG

```
ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              child: controller.userUiModel == null ||
                      controller.userUiModel!.photo == null
                  ? Container(
                      color: AppColors.colorBlack,
                      height: 88,
                      width: 88,
                    )
                  : Image.network(
                      controller.userUiModel!.photo!,
                      scale: 88,
                    ),
            ),
```